# Is it correct to refer to Canadian geese?

Tags: terminology, animals

The Canada goose is a migratory species which lives in northern parts of the northern hemisphere - including the Arctic, as well as temperate regions of North America and northern Europe. In winter we have a lot of them in the UK, which I understand are mostly resident here all the year round. Some migrate from Greenland and Iceland, in winter and a few from Canada. But for the most part they are very unlikely ever to have been in Canada.

“*Canada goose*” is the name of the species. But I’ve noticed a tendency on the part of the BBC to refer to “*Canadian* geese”. Hesitating to take on the august BBC on a matter of correct terminology I believe this is quite wrong. It should be “Canada geese”. Canadian goose suggests one of no particular species which has been brought here from Canada.

Am I right?

Comment: Wikipedia mentions that "the Canada goose is also colloquially referred to as the "Canadian goose"." [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada_goose#cite_note-8)

Comment: Must-see post from Outdoors StackExchange: [Is the correct term Canada Goose or Canadian Goose?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18146/is-the-correct-term-canada-goose-or-canadian-goose)

Comment: In UK the Canada goose population is mostly sedentary (they do not migrate). So they aren't "Canadian geese". I realise though, that the so-called "English muffin" does not migrate, yet it isn't called the "England muffin".

Comment: Are you sure 'Canadian goose' is being used in the classifier (Branta canadensis) rather than the identifier (any goose from / spending most of its life in Canada'?

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for your correction about the sedentary nature of the Canada goose. My wife has just pointed that out to me, with reference to a book on birds. Apparently a few genuinely wild ones do cross the Atlantic and get mixed up with our "feral" ones, as the book calls them.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. Evan Davis on PM this evening referred to some "Canadian geese" in a park in Birmingham.

Comment: Just an explanation of my edit. I have taken BBC out of the title so that the question is just whether or not Canadian Goose is allowable. This leaves the question and its motivation intact, but removes the questionable implication that the BBC is systematically using this term.

Comment: @David I have no objection whatever to your doing that. But it is just that Auntie (BBC), has always been seen as the guardian of all that is right and proper, including as regards the nomenclature we use and the way in which we speak. I have the BBC pronunciation dictionary (for names and places) on my shelf, but unfortunately it doesn't extend to names of birds etc.

Answer (score 1):

The poster did not provide a quotation to support his statement, so, although I do not regard the BBC as an authority on the English language, I feel obliged to come to its defence on this one. Searching the BBC News website for “Canadian geese” I only found an example of “Canada Geese”:

[A local Birmingham news item dated 14th January 2022](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-60007531) has:

> Bird flu has been confirmed in **Canada geese** in a city’s parks. 
> The A(H5N1) strain of avian influenza has been found in geese in Cannon
> Hill Park and Witton Lakes in Birmingham, the city council said.

And it is illustrated with a picture (from Getty images) of what I take to be a Canada goose.

Searching the [BBC News website for “Canada Geese”](https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=Canada+geese&page=1) I found more examples, although many of a single story.

*So I rather think this, er, cooks the poster’s goose.*

Answer (score -1):

> Is the BBC correct in referring to Canadian geese?

No, they are not.

> Am I right?

Yes, you are.

The Canada Goose is a specific species *Branta canadensis* and "Canada Goose" is a proper noun.

The Iceland Gull *(Larus Glaucoides)* may be found in Iceland but it not called the "Icelandic Gull".

We would not call a person called "David England" "English David".

Comment: But 'China tea' and 'Chinese tea' are seen as synonyms. (I won't bother adding references. Though I follow ELU guidelines in doing so when writing 'answers'.)